# Getting error when attempting to use proxy server in Node.js / Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am attempting to use a proxy within my Node.js / Puppeteer application and receiving errors.

If I remove the proxy code, the application runs as intended.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'], headless: false});
```

I expect the application to run as usual, but with a different IP.

Error received: ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED

Comment: I have written step-by-step instructions for configuring proxy with Puppeteer. https://dev.to/gajus/using-http-proxy-with-puppeteer-di1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either your proxy is not working or puppeteer is rejecting it because it is most likely using a self-signed cert. To fix a cert issue add the following args.

```
args: [
    '--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'
    '--ignore-certificate-errors',
    '--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list '
]
```

See: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1159

Comment: try: telnet 127.0.0.1 9050 should at least connect you may have to enable telnet on windows or install it on linux

Comment: I meant to use the command line tool telnet to test if the proxy is working

Comment: You will need to give some information about your proxy. It seems like you don't have a proxy?

Comment: delete this and try your code again: '--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'